# How to monitor for and react to changes to Python objects?

Tags: python, multithreading, monitoring, introspection

I'm building a Python application that interfaces with several hardware subsystems, each of which has its own interface thread.  The design was for the subsystems to be very independent, with only high-level data provided to the main app.  I just found out that some of the subsystems interact in complex ways that require the interface for one subsystem to get low-level data from the interface to another subsystem.

The data is deep within the interface, and I don't want to refactor the overall system just to share this data (the main app couldn't care less about it).

What I'd like to do is apply a decorator to the specific item needing to be monitored (class attribute, instance attribute, or a simple variable) that would send a message (event + value) to a listener or spooler whenever the item's value is updated.  The listener should be able to sleep on the message, so it can react quickly (in real-time) to changes, but the listener interface should also provide buffering if the listener has to poll for the data.

I do know the item being monitored must have its `__setattr__()` call wrapped.  I got some hints from this ([Decorating a class to monitor attribute changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812341/decorating-a-class-to-monitor-attribute-changes)), but it doesn't look at the listening side.

The data could be sent to something like a pipe or queue, so the listener can be slower than the writer and not miss any updates.

But how would the writer and listener connect?  They are independent threads of execution, and different modules, so the data items could be assigned a globally-unique string name (e.g., "HyperBleegRate") that would be a parameter to the decorator (and also known to the listener).  The first attempted write or read (they would be asynchronous) would cause a pipe or queue to be created, with the write end returned to the writer and the read end to the reader.

I've looked at the Python introspection tools, but they appear to be passive, and don't generate triggers when a data item is updated.  The profiling tools add too much overhead.

Ideally, the execution cost of the decorator should be as low as a simple value copy operation, but at worst a cpickle call could be tolerated.  In the future it should be possible to use different communication methods (list, deque, queue, pipe, UDP socket, JSON, ...).  But a zero-copy solution would be ideal when the writer and reader share the same memory space.

On top of it all, it should work cross-platform, including under Windows.  It must be thread-safe.  I suspect it may eventually become useful for several items to be monitored by a single listener in a `select()`-like way.

What's the simplest way to start?  I'm willing to do the heavy-lifting to get this written, but I'm needing some major clues.

I suspect something like this ***must*** already exist, and I've simply failed to say the right magic words to the Search Gods.

Comment: Obviously, the simplest way to start is to put aside an infinite wish list and write *anything* concrete "that works" for a single attribute of a single class.  Play with that until you're happy with it.  Generalize and abstract later.  The way these things usually end is with a numbingly complex framework that nobody but the author understands, let alone is able to debug or extend.  The author loses those abilities too after taking a 2-week break - good luck ;-)

Comment: My first approach is to make a module that uses a module global to hold a dictionary of the names and the transfer mechanism they map to (a deque at present).  The module provides 2 functions: request_reader(name) and request_writer(name).  When called, each will look up or create the appropriate dictionary entry, and return a function that will cause passed data to be pushed or the top of the queue to be popped, as appropriate.  The intent is to create a deque for each data item being shared.  Once that works, I'll try implementing something under a traditional file handle.