# How to identify when an attribute's attribute is being set?

Tags: python, properties, attributes

I have a mutable object (which we'll call `mutable`) that has multiple attributes. This object is itself an attribute in a class `Foo`. `Foo` is user-defined while `mutable` is not and thus cannot be changed.

Whenever someone is trying to set the attributes in `mutable`, I'll need to make computations. The problem I'm facing is that using a property for `mutable` only works when `mutable` itself is set, and not its attributes. I've managed to solve the problem but with something that seems more of a hack than reasonable Python code.

```
class Mutable(object):  # Example class.

    def __init__(self):
        self.attr0 = 0
        self.attr1 = 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)[1:-1]


class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._mutable = Mutable()

    @property
    def mutable(self):
        print('mutable was read')
        return self._mutable

    @mutable.setter
    def mutable(self, attr_value_pair):
        attribute, value = attr_value_pair
        setattr(self._mutable, attribute, value)
        print('mutable.' + attribute, 'was set to', value)


bar = Foo()
print(bar.mutable)           # 'mutable was read'
bar.mutable = ('attr0', 5)   # 'mutable.attr0 was set to 5'
bar.mutable = ('attr1', 10)  # 'mutable.attr1 was set to 10'
print(bar.mutable)           # 'mutable was read'

# This is what I want to do but it only calls the getter.
bar.mutable.attr0 = 0        # 'mutable was read'
bar.mutable.attr1 = 1        # 'mutable was read'
```

Is there a way I can identify when an attribute in `mutable` is set in a more Pythonic manner?

**EDIT:** To clarify: `Foo` needs to know when `mutable` changes because `Foo` has attributes that depends on `mutable`. `Mutable` can be inherited.

Comment: Define a class `MutableWrapper` with normal `property`s which delegates to `Mutable`.

Comment: Maybe you could add the `@setter` to a method of the `Mutable` class that sets each of the attributes

Comment: @AlexHall So a class that inherits `Mutable` and then create a property for each attribute, alternatively override `__setattr__()`? That might work, but the computations is supposed to be done in `Foo` so I'm not sure how `Foo` would detect changes in `mutable`. I'll try out and test the idea though!

Comment: @lucianopaz The `Mutable` class is not defined by me but is a third-party/built-in class. The class in the question is just a mock-up to describe my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Revised***

Basically I agree with @Alessandro's [derived-class approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41331493/355230), namely that you should extend the `Mutable` class—however with a couple of significant differences. One is that, given that it's derived from the base class, there's no need for it also **contain** an separate (unused) instance of the base class. I missed this in my earlier version of this answer.

More importantly, is that it supports user-supplied callback functions which will be called whenever one of its attributes is read or written. This allows the notifications to be sent back to methods in the contain class—`Foo` in the case—which is where I believe their being changed really needs to be handled.

**Note:** this does *not* necessarily mean you can remove the `Foo` property `mutable`. It'll still be needed if you want to support the tuple-assignment operation you've implemented which allows statements like: `bar.mutable = ('attr0', 5)` to set `mutable`'s `attr0` attribute. Without the property you would need to write: `bar.mutable.attr0 = 5` instead (which might be clearer anyway).

```
class Mutable(object):  # Example class (unchangeable).
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr0 = 0
        self.attr1 = 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)[1:-1]

class MonitoredMutable(Mutable):
    _get_callback = _set_callback = lambda *_: None  # no-op placeholders

    def __init__(self, get_callback, set_callback):
        # use superclass to avoid infinite recursion when setting attributes
        super_delegate = super(MonitoredMutable, self)
        super_delegate.__init__()
        super_delegate.__setattr__('_get_callback', get_callback)
        super_delegate.__setattr__('_set_callback', set_callback)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        super(MonitoredMutable, self).__setattr__(name, value)
        self._set_callback(name, value)  # write notification

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        self._get_callback(name)  # read notification
        return super(MonitoredMutable, self).__getattr__(name, value)

    def __repr__(self):  # optional
        # override to only display the public attributes of the instance
        public_attrs = {k:v for k,v in self.__dict__.items()
                            if not k.startswith('_')}
        # assuming single inheritance (only one base class)
        base_classname = self.__class__.__bases__[0].__name__
        return base_classname + ': ' + (str(public_attrs)[1:-1] if public_attrs
                                        else 'No pub attributes')

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._mutable = MonitoredMutable(self._get_callback, self._set_callback)

    def _get_callback(self, name):
        print('mutable.' + name + ' was read')

    def _set_callback(self, name, value):
        print('mutable.' + name, 'was set to', value)

    @property
    def mutable(self):
        return self._mutable

    @mutable.setter
    def mutable(self, attr_value_pair):
        attribute, value = attr_value_pair
        setattr(self._mutable, attribute, value)

bar = Foo()
print(bar.mutable)           # -> Mutable: 'attr0': 0, 'attr1': 1
bar.mutable = ('attr0', 5)   # -> mutable.attr0 was set to 5
bar.mutable = ('attr1', 10)  # -> mutable.attr1 was set to 10
print(bar.mutable)           # -> Mutable: 'attr0': 5, 'attr1': 10

# These now work
bar.mutable.attr0 = 1        # -> mutable.attr0 was set to 1
bar.mutable.attr1 = 0        # -> mutable.attr1 was set to 0
print(bar.mutable)           # -> Mutable: 'attr0': 1, 'attr1': 0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! I can even remove the properties. I'm just having little trouble understanding everything in `MonitoredMutable`. By not calling `super().__init__()` you're actually not inheriting `Mutable`, but instead you're just using the superclass to avoid the recursion problem for setting attributes?

Comment: It effectively calls `super().__init__()` when it sets its `_mutable` attribute. Also, it's using the superclass' `__setattr__()` because doing it directly with something like `self._mutable = Mutable()` would call its own `__setattr__()` otherwise which is undesireable. Since its base class, `Mutable`, doesn't have a customized `__setattr__()` of its own, the task ends up being performed by the built-in `object.__setattr__()` method—which is what is wanted. If my answer solves your problem, please accept it.

Comment: Ignore my previous comments about how the base class was being initialized—it wasn't but that fact wasn't obvious. I think the revised answer will clear up most if not all of your questions.

Comment: Your revised answer cleared up all my questions. I believe I should remove the `mutable` property since it's not as readable and feels unnecessary. But other than that this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you remove the `mutable` property, you'll probably also want to change the statement in the `__init__()` to `self.mutable = MonitoredMutable(self._get_callback, self._set_callback)` (if you still want a public `Foo.mutable` attribute).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest clean solution would be to subclass `mutable` - but I assume this is not an option here.

The simplest "quick&dirty" solution would be to monkeypatch `mutable` - but this is really a last-resort solution and looking for troubles in the long term.

So if you can't subclass `mutable` nor control it's instanciation and don't want to monkeypatch it, you're left with the `proxy` pattern.

edit : oh and yes since it's `Foo` that needs to get notified of changes to `self._mutable`, you have to combine this with the observer pattern (here in a very restricted form):

```
class Mutable(object):  # Example class.

    def __init__(self):
        self.attr0 = 0
        self.attr1 = 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)[1:-1]



class MutableProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, mutable, owner):
        self._mutable = mutable
        self._owner = owner

    @property
    def attr0(self):
        return self._mutable.attr0

    @attr0.setter
    def attr0(self, value):
        self._mutable.attr0 = value 
        self._owner.notify("set", "attr0", value)


    @property
    def attr1(self):
        return self._mutable.attr1

    @attr1.setter
    def attr1(self, value):
        self._mutable.attr1 = value 
        self._owner.notify("attr1", value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<MutableProxy for {}>".format(repr(self._mutable))

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mutable = Mutable()

    @property
    def mutable(self):
        #print('mutable was read')
        return self._mutable

    @mutable.setter
    def mutable(self, value):
        self._mutable = MutableProxy(value, self)

    def notify(self, attrname, value):
        print('self._mutable.{} was set to {}'.format(attrname, value))
```

NB : I didn't add any typechecking in `MutableProxy.__init__`, depending on what your real `mutable` actually is you may want to make sure you at least get something compatible...

NB2: I used explicit properties on `ProxyMutable` because it makes things clearer, but you may want to use `__getattr__` / `__setattr__` hooks instead (at least for `mutable` attributes you don't need to control access to).

NB3 : We now have a cyclic reference between `Foo` and `MutableProxy`. Python normalluy knows how to get rid of cyclic references but if it happened to still be an issue for your concrete use case you may want to make `MutableProxy._owner` a [weak reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html) instead.

**Now the question that bugs me** is: why do you expose `mutable` at all ? Hiding it completely and only providing access to it's attributes thru `Foo` methods or properties would make for a much simpler code (and one that's much easier to reason about and less likely to have unexpected side effects too).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I was a bit unclear in my question. The `Foo` class needs to know when an attribute in `mutable` has been set. Some attributes in `Foo` are dependent on the state of `mutable` and thus needs to be recalculated.

Comment: Uhu ok, I missed that point. Cf my edited snippet for an exemple with the added `Observer` pattern (in a _very_ primitive form).

Comment: The reason why I expose `mutable` is for naming purposes. Say that a `Parent` has a `Child` which has a `name`; it would be clear to say `parent.child.name = 'Amanda'`. Also, if the `mutable` has many attributes (20-30) it would require me to add many getters and setters. If I've understood your suggestion correctly. Your observer pattern seems like a good solution because I could just inherit `Mutable` and add `self._owner.notify()` in `__setattr__`. I'll play around a bit more and do some testing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach which effectively replaces the `__setattr__()` method to instances of the existing class. I derived the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18812380/355230) by @Martijn Pieters to a related question titled [*Decorating a class to monitor attribute changes*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812341/decorating-a-class-to-monitor-attribute-changes).

The code below supports an instance `id` that is passed on the `notify()` notification function. Having this isn't a requirement and exists only to verify that the function is only getting called when the associated instance object is set/modified. It can be removed if you don't need it.

```
from types import FunctionType, MethodType

class Mutable(object):  # Example class (unchangeable).
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr0 = 0
        self.attr1 = 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)[1:-1]

def monitor_attr_changes(obj, id, notify):
    """ Change class of obj to one that supports attribute notifications. """
    old_setattr = getattr(obj, '__setattr__')
    old_classname = obj.__class__.__name__

    class NewClass(obj.__class__):
        def __setattr__(self, name, value):
            old_setattr(name, value)
            notify(id, name, value)

        def __repr__(self):  # Not required -- here only for demo purposes.
            data_attrs = {name: value for name, value in self.__dict__.items()
                          if not isinstance(value, (FunctionType, MethodType))}
            return old_classname + ': ' + str(data_attrs)[1:-1]

    obj.__class__ = NewClass
    return obj

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
        print('creating instance {!r} of Mutable class'.format(id))
        self.mutable = monitor_attr_changes(Mutable(), id, self._callback)

    def _callback(self, id, name, value):
        print('{} notification: {} has been set to {}'.format(id, name, value))

foo = Foo('foo')
bar = Foo('bar')
print(foo.mutable)          # -> Mutable: 'attr0': 0, 'attr1': 1
foo.mutable.attr0 = 5       # -> foo notification: attr0 has been set to 5
bar.mutable.attr0 = 42      # -> bar notification: attr0 has been set to 42
foo.mutable.attr1 = 10      # -> foo notification: attr1 has been set to 10
print(foo.mutable)          # -> Mutable: 'attr0': 5, 'attr1': 10
foo.mutable.attr0 = 1       # -> foo notification: attr0 has been set to 1
foo.mutable.attr1 = 0       # -> foo notification: attr1 has been set to 0
print(foo.mutable)          # -> Mutable: 'attr0': 1, 'attr1': 0
print(foo.mutable.attr0)    # -> 1
print(bar.mutable.attr0)    # -> 42                                        x
```

Comment: I appreciate your still providing answers :) This one was interesting as well. I've played around with the idea for a while and the only problem I had was that every instance of `Foo` got notified if an attribute or `Mutable` was changed. It might be good in some cases and I certainly learned a few tricks, but it wasn't applicable in my case. Also, I'm not sure if `_SENTINEL` and `old` has any usage, or is there something I'm missing here? Once again, I really appreciate you providing more than necessary to help me with my problem.

Comment: I'm still working on it because I think it's an interesting problem (and I'm not totally satisfied with my other answer). You've astutely noticed I left a couple of unused variables, `_SENTINEL` and `old` that are just leftovers from the linked answer about monitoring attribute changes (and can be removed). I'll see if there a way to fix this to differentiate between different `Foo` instances and update this answer accordingly—if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Foo class cannot detect when Mutable changes.

You need to either extend your Mutable class and detect changes there or wrap it to read/write from the wrapper.

```py
class MutableWrapper(Mutable):

    def __init__(self):
        self._mutable = Mutable()

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        print('mutable.' + key, 'was set to', value)
        super().__setattr__(key, value)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print('mutable was read')
        super().__getattribute__(item)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._mutable.__dict__)[1:-1]


class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._mutable = MutableWrapper()

    @property
    def mutable(self):
        return self._mutable

    @mutable.setter
    def mutable(self, attr_value_pair):
        attribute, value = attr_value_pair
        setattr(self._mutable, attribute, value)
```

Comment: Sure it can, the example in the question works in that manner. My question is if there's a more intuitive and Pythonic way to go about, since setting a tuple to an attribute to change the attribute's attribute is just confusing. I want to be able to recalculate attributes in `Foo` that depend on the state of `mutable`, so I cannot create a wrapper unless it can inform `Foo` in some way that `mutable` has been changed.

Comment: Why does the derived class  `MutableWrapper` also need the separate instance of a base class object stored in `self._mutable`?

Comment: It does not need, of course. I think I made a mistake while copying code. Thanks for having found it.