# raise flag if attribute is changed results in too many properties?

Tags: python, properties, attributes

For my application I have an object which has some set of attributes. One set of attributes, the parameters, can be accessed and adjusted by the user. The other set of attributes, the outputs, should be accessible by the user but are calculated using internal methods. Furthermore, if any of the parameter attributes are adjusted the outputs must also be re-calculated from the internal methods and adjusted accordingly. However, as these calculations may be costly I do not want to needlessly run them unless (or until) they are requested.

Currently I can implement this by making each "parameter" attribute a property and including a `self.calculated` flag which is raised whenever any of the parameters are changed and also making each "output" attribute a property which checks the `self.calculated` flag and accordingly either returns the output directly if no calculation is needed or performs the calculation, lowers the flag, and returns the output.

See code

```
class Rectangle(object):

    def __init__(self, length=1, width=1):
        self._length = length
        self._width = width
        self._area = self.calc_area()
        self._perim = self.calc_perim()
        self.calculated = True

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self._length

    @length.setter
    def length(self, value):
        if value != self._length:
            self._length = value
            self.calculated = False

    @property
    def width(self):
        return self._width

    @width.setter
    def width(self, value):
        if value != self._width:
            self._width = value
            self.calculated = False

    @property
    def area(self):
        if self.calculated is True:
            return self._area
        else:
            self.recalculate()
            return self._area

    @property
    def perim(self):
        if self.calculated is True:
            return self._perim
        else:
            self.recalculate()
            return self._perim

    def calc_area(self):
        return self.length * self.width

    def calc_perim(self):
        return 2 * (self.length + self.width)

    def recalculate(self):
        self._area = self.calc_area()
        self._perim = self.calc_perim()
        self.calculated = True

    def double_width(self):
        self.width = 2 * self.width
```

This gives the desired behavior but seems like an excessive proliferation of properties which would be especially problematic if there got to be a large number of parameters and outputs.

Is there a cleaner way to implement this attribute change/recalculation structure? I have found a couple of posts where a solution is presented involving writing a `__setattr__` method for the class but I'm not sure if that would be straight forward to implement in my since the behavior should be different depending on the particular attribute being set. I guess this could be handled with a check in the `__setattr__` method about whether the attribute is a parameter or output...

[Decorating a class to monitor attribute changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812341/decorating-a-class-to-monitor-attribute-changes)

[How to identify when an attribute's attribute is being set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330968/how-to-identify-when-an-attributes-attribute-is-being-set?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different options, and which to use is highly dependent on the use case. Clearly, the options below can be quite bad in many use cases.

**Delete outputs when inputs change**

An example of implementing this:

```
@width.setter
def width(self, value):
    if value != self._width:
        self._width = value
        (self._area,self._perim) = (None,None)

def perim(self):
    if not self._perim:
        self._perim = calc_perim(self)
    return self._perim
```

This doesn't address most of your concern, but it does get rid of the `calculated` flag (and while your code recalculates all of the outputs when any of them are requested after an update, this code just calculates the requested one).

**Update values when inputs change**

When you increase the width by x, the perimeter increases by 2*x and the area increases by x*length. In some cases, applying formulae such as these  to update the values as the inputs change can be more efficient that calculating the outputs from scratch every time the inputs change.

**Keep track of last values**

Whenever you calculate the outputs, keep track not only of what results you got, but what inputs you used to calculate them. Then next time an object is asked what its outputs are, it can check whether the outputs were calculated according to its current attributes. Obviously, this requires multiplying the input storage space.

**Memoization**

Going even further than the previous option, create a dictionary where the keys are tuples of attributes, and the values are output. If you currently have a function `calculate_output(attributes)`, replace all calls to the function with

```
def output_lookup(attributes):
   if not attributes in output_dict.keys():
          output_dict[attributes] = calculate_output(attributes)
   return output_dict[attributes]
```

You should use this option if you expect particular combinations of attributes to be repeated often, calculating the outputs is expensive, and/or memory is cheap. This can be shared across the class, so if you have several instances of rectangles that have the same length and width, you can have one `(_perim,_area)` value stored, rather than duplicating it across each instance. So for *some* use cases, this can be more efficient.

Note that your issue ultimately derives from the fact that you are trying to engage in *some* memoization (you want to save the results from your calculations, so that when someone accesses an object's outputs, you don't have to calculate the outputs if they've already been calculated for the current inputs), but you need to keep track of when to "invalidate the cache", so to speak. If you were to simply treat the area and perimeter as methods rather than attributes, or you were to treats instances as immutable and require resetting attributes be done by creating a new instance with the new values, you would eliminate the complexities that you've added to the length and width. You can't have it all: you can't have cached values from mutable attributes without some overhead.

PS `is True` is redundant in `if self.calculated is True:`.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough response. Your are right that my question is fundamentally about memoization, a concept I hadn't thought formally about until now! Incidentally for my application I think it will be best to treat the objects as immutable as you suggest. At least as things are now the objects should really only be created and calculated once. I was interested in the possibility of parameters being adjusted for future expansions. If needed I think keeping track of the old inputs and comparing them to the new inputs when the outputs are requested will be the best way for me.